# Use variable in Ansible template

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2

I need to create a file via jinja template but facing some issues.

My Variable

```yaml
my:
  acl:
        - name: test
          allow:
            - 0.0.0.0
          deny:
            - 1.1.1.1
        - name: china
          allow:
            - 1.2.3.4
          deny:
            - 10.10.10.10
```

My Task:

```yaml
- name: Create acl file
  template:
    force: yes
    src: acl.conf.j2
    dest: "/etc/nginx/conf.d/{{ item.name }}.conf"
  become: yes
  with_items:
    - "{{ my.acl }}"
```

My Template

```yaml
{% for allow in my.acl %}
allow {{allow.allow}};
{% endfor %}
{% for deny in my.acl %}
deny {{deny.deny}};
{% endfor %}
```

Result china.conf

```sh
allow ['0.0.0.0'];
allow ['1.2.3.4'];
deny ['1.1.1.1'];
deny ['10.10.10.10'];
```

Result test.conf

```sh
allow ['0.0.0.0'];
allow ['1.2.3.4'];
deny ['1.1.1.1'];
deny ['10.10.10.10'];
```

I need in the china file only the ip addresses that are defined in the object china without the [' ']

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix the template

```yaml
{% for allow in item.allow %}
allow {{ allow }};
{% endfor %}
{% for deny in item.deny %}
deny {{ deny }};
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You're welcome! FWIW, see [Ansible role Nginx](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-nginx) and [encode_nginx](https://github.com/jtyr/ansible-config_encoder_filters#id12)

Answer (score -1):

Add an `if` and print the first object in the `allow` and `deny` list:

```yaml
{% for allow in my.acl %}
  {% if allow.name == 'china' %}
    allow {{ allow.allow[0] }};
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% for deny in my.acl %}
  {% if allow.name == 'china' %}
    deny {{ deny.deny[0] }};
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If the allow and deny lists will have more than one element use this:

```yaml
{% for allow in my.acl %}
  {% if allow.name == 'china' %}
    {% for ip in allow.allow %}
      allow {{ ip }};
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% for deny in my.acl %}
  {% if deny.name == 'china' %}
    {% for ip in deny.deny %}
      deny {{ ip }};
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I need to have a more general template because on some servers I have more than two files -Is that possible? So for each acl name I need to create the acl files.

A server can have

```yaml
my:
  acl:
        - name: test
          allow:
            - 0.0.0.0
          deny:
            - 1.1.1.1
        - name: china
          allow:
            - 1.2.3.4
          deny:
            - 10.10.10.10
        - name: test2
          allow:
            - 1.1.1.1
            - 2.2.2.2
       - name: test3
         deny:
           - 10.10.0.0/24
```